# How to add Header names in xls files from sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/report/sample.xls", 'w')
 { |f| f.write
 ( @policies) 
 }
```

Above code is working fine its creating xls file in tmp folder, but i want header names in that xls file, how to pass header names in that code? this code written in sidekiq for background process. please any one suggest me

#### sampl.xls file:

```
[{"id"=>1, "office"=>" ", "ordernumber"=>"100", "code"=>"NA", "type"=>"I", "prev_order_number"=>nil, "insured_name"=>"sree"}]
```

Comment: Please add a sample lines from your `sample.xls` file.

Comment: That's not Excel, but JSON. Do you want JSON or XLS?

Comment: i want xls but data getting json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSV to save resources. Excel will open it without any problems.

```
csv_file = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << @policies.first.keys
    @policies.each do |policy|
        csv << policy.values
    end
end

File.write("#{Rails.root}/tmp/report/sample.xls", csv_file)
```

---

#### Previuos answer

If code you provided is doing exactly what you want, then try this:

```
headers = {col1: "id", col2: "office", col3: "ordernumber", col4: "code", col5: "type", col6: "prev_order_number", col7: "insured_name"}

File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/report/sample.xls", 'w') do |f|
  f.write @policies.unshift(headers)
end
```

Comment: [ {col1: "id", col2: "office", col3: "ordernumber", col4: "code", col5: "type", col6: "prev_order_number", col7: "insured_name"} {"id"=>1, "office"=>" ", "ordernumber"=>"100", "code"=>"NA", "type"=>"I", "prev_order_number"=>nil, "insured_name"=>"sree"}]

Comment: it coming like this , but i want  id as heading in in below list of id numbers, header office and in below of office list of office names like that i want

Comment: @SrikanthRao consider selecting the answer to mark your question *closed*.